# Python range error along with outcome error

Tags: python, range, calculator

I'm doing a python sort of grade calculator right now and i need to make the program display ‘Out of range’ if credits entered are not in the range 0, 20, 40,60, 80, 100 and 120.
[Where it says incorrect it should say Out of range instead](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUBY6.png)
[This is the spec of the grade calc im trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfwPi.png)
so far everything works apart from Part 1B where its supposed to display out of range
[Second bullet point is the problem im struggling with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGhWq.png)

```
def Validation(StudentPassCredits, StudentDeferCredits, StudentFailCredits):
    if StudentPassCredits + StudentDeferCredits + StudentFailCredits == 120:

        if StudentPassCredits % 20 != 0 or StudentDeferCredits % 20 != 0 or StudentFailCredits % 20 != 0:
            print('Range error')
          
        else:
            Main_Version()

    else:
        print('Total incorrect')
```

I tried this but it wouldnt work and only displays Total incorrect instead of range error and i dont really know what to do now.

[The rest of the program works as needed its just the out of range thats the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEkkl.png)

```
def Main_Version():
    if StudentPassCredits == 120:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Progress')

    elif StudentPassCredits == 100:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Progress (module trailer)')

    elif StudentFailCredits >= 80:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Exclude')

    else:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Do not progress – module retriever')

def Validation(StudentPassCredits, StudentDeferCredits, StudentFailCredits):
    if StudentPassCredits + StudentDeferCredits + StudentFailCredits == 120:

        if StudentPassCredits % 20 != 0 or StudentDeferCredits % 20 != 0 or StudentFailCredits % 20 != 0:
            print('Range error')
          
        else:
            Main_Version()

    else:
        print('Total incorrect')
try:
    StudentPassCredits = int(input('Please enter your current pass credits: '))
    StudentDeferCredits = int(input('Please enter your current defer credits: '))
    StudentFailCredits = int(input('Please enter your current fail credits: '))

    Validation(StudentPassCredits, StudentDeferCredits, StudentFailCredits) 

except ValueError:
    print('Integer required')
```

However,
With help i managed to fix the range issue but its lead to another issue.

```
def Main_Version():
    if StudentPassCredits == 120:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Progress')


    elif StudentPassCredits == 100:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Progress (module trailer)')


    elif StudentFailCredits >= 80:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Exclude')


    else:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Do not progress – module retriever')


def _validate_credits_in_range(credits: int, container: "Container[int]" = range(0, 121, 20)) -> bool:
    return credits in container

def Validation(StudentPassCredits: int, StudentDeferCredits: int, StudentFailCredits: int) -> None:
    if all(_validate_credits_in_range(credits) for credits in(StudentPassCredits, StudentDeferCredits, StudentFailCredits)):
        if StudentPassCredits + StudentDeferCredits + StudentFailCredits == 120:
            print('Total incorrect')
        else:
            Main_Version()
    else:
        print('Range error')


try:
    StudentPassCredits = int(input('Please enter your current pass credits: '))
    StudentDeferCredits = int(input('Please enter your current defer credits: '))
    StudentFailCredits = int(input('Please enter your current fail credits: '))

    Validation(StudentPassCredits, StudentDeferCredits, StudentFailCredits) 

except ValueError:
    print('Integer required')
```

[This is how i fixed the range error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wo87T.png)
[This is the issue it is causing now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGcvj.png). The output should print "Progress but it doesnt"

If anybody can help by either letting me know how to fix the range error via a different method that still keeps the program working or keeping the current method to fix the range error but also fixes the progress error then please let me know.

New Method (range works but progression outcome does not)

```
def Main_Version():
    if StudentPassCredits == 120:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Progress')


    elif StudentPassCredits == 100:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Progress (module trailer)')


    elif StudentFailCredits >= 80:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Exclude')


    else:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Do not progress – module retriever')


def _validate_credits_in_range(credits: int, container: "Container[int]" = range(0, 121, 20)) -> bool:
    return credits in container

def Validation(StudentPassCredits: int, StudentDeferCredits: int, StudentFailCredits: int) -> None:
    if all(_validate_credits_in_range(credits) for credits in(StudentPassCredits, StudentDeferCredits, StudentFailCredits)):
        if StudentPassCredits + StudentDeferCredits + StudentFailCredits == 120:
            print('Total incorrect')
        else:
            Main_Version()
    else:
        print('Range error')


try:
    StudentPassCredits = int(input('Please enter your current pass credits: '))
    StudentDeferCredits = int(input('Please enter your current defer credits: '))
    StudentFailCredits = int(input('Please enter your current fail credits: '))

    Validation(StudentPassCredits, StudentDeferCredits, StudentFailCredits) 

except ValueError:
    print('Integer required')
```

Old method (progression outcome works but range doesnt)

```
def Main_Version():
    if StudentPassCredits == 120:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Progress')

    elif StudentPassCredits == 100:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Progress (module trailer)')

    elif StudentFailCredits >= 80:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Exclude')

    else:
        print('Your academic year progression outcome is :', 'Do not progress – module retriever')

def Validation(StudentPassCredits, StudentDeferCredits, StudentFailCredits):
    if StudentPassCredits + StudentDeferCredits + StudentFailCredits == 120:

        if StudentPassCredits % 20 != 0 or StudentDeferCredits % 20 != 0 or StudentFailCredits % 20 != 0:
            print('Range error')

        else:
            Main_Version()

    else:
        print('Total incorrect')
try:
    StudentPassCredits = int(input('Please enter your current pass credits: '))
    StudentDeferCredits = int(input('Please enter your current defer credits: '))
    StudentFailCredits = int(input('Please enter your current fail credits: '))

    Validation(StudentPassCredits, StudentDeferCredits, StudentFailCredits) 

except ValueError:
    print('Integer required')
```

Comment: Sorry I couldn't read that much code :).   Consider reducing your problem to the least amount of code required to repeat the problem.  You may find that in doing so, you'll probably figure out what the problem is yourself.

Comment: If range and total are both incorrect, what do you expect the output to be?

Comment: I think you should take a close look at how you are calculating the total number of credits, and what should happen when it equals/doesn't equal 120.

Comment: The next to last example has `if StudentPassCredits + StudentDeferCredits + StudentFailCredits == 120: print('Total incorrect')` - what do you expect it to do when those three values add up to 120?